# Compare two column values

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting

> Run-Time error '1004'

when trying to compare two column values

Completely new to VBA and self-taught have no idea where I'm going wrong. Don't care about making the code efficient, just want to compare the values in the cells and output the difference. I know a little bit of other languages but I don't know enough to understand where the error is.

```
Sub CompareTwoColumns()

Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
Dim dif As Integer, counter As Integer, val1 As Integer, val2 As Integer

    Set col1 = Columns("A")
    Set col2 = Columns("B")

    LastR = Columns("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    counter = 0
    
    Do While counter <> LastR
        
        val1 = Cells(counter, col1.Column).Value
        val2 = Cells(counter, col2.Column).Value
        
        counter = counter + 1
        
        dif = val1 - val2
        dif = Abs(dif)
        
        Cells(counter, "C") = dif
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `val1 = Cells(counter, col1.Column).Value` will fail when `counter` is zero, since there's no row zero...  Move `counter = counter + 1` to just below `Do While counter <> LastR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro had a problem in the line val1 = Cells(counter, col1.Column).Value and val2 = Cells(counter, col2.Column).Value. The counter variable is initialized to 0, but the cells in Excel are indexed from 1. This will generate an out of range index error.

Also add an additional check to ensure that no empty cells are processed in the columns.

```html
Sub CompareTwoColumns()
    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
    Dim dif As Integer, counter As Integer, val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant
    
    Set col1 = Columns("A")
    Set col2 = Columns("B")
    
    LastR = Columns("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    counter = 1
    
    Do While counter <= LastR
        val1 = col1.Cells(counter).Value
        val2 = col2.Cells(counter).Value
        
        ' Verify that both cells contain values before comparing
        If Not IsEmpty(val1) And Not IsEmpty(val2) Then
            dif = Abs(val1 - val2)
            Cells(counter, "C").Value = dif
        End If
        
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few simple changes will fix this. What @Tim Williams said, and don't skip the last row.

`counter = 0`: row/column index starts at 1; 0 will generate the error you saw. Initialize with `counter = 1`

`Do While counter <> LastR` skips the last row; use `Do While counter <= LastR`

Don't increment counter until input/output is complete.

I don't recall making any other edits, but better check!

```
Sub CompareTwoColumns()

    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
    Dim dif As Integer, counter As Integer, val1 As Integer, val2 As Integer

    Set col1 = Columns("A")
    Set col2 = Columns("B")

    LastR = Columns("A:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    counter = 1  ' Row or column cannot be 0
    
    Do While counter <= LastR  ' Allow = to include the last row
        
        val1 = Cells(counter, col1.Column).Value
        val2 = Cells(counter, col2.Column).Value
        
        dif = val1 - val2
        dif = Abs(dif)
        
        Cells(counter, "C") = dif
        
        counter = counter + 1  ' Don't increment counter until we're done with I/O
        
    Loop

End Sub
```